# Filtro com Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filtro, filter, back-end

Tenho uma lista de itens salvas em uma coleção do Mongo, gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar o array original.
Segue o código

```
api.filtra = function (req, res) {
    model.find()
        .then(function(itens) {
            for(i = 0; i < itens.length; i++)
                console.log(itens[i].criterio);                
                res.json(itens);

                console.log("testeA");
                var filtrado = itens.filter(
                    itens, {"genero": "0"}
                );
                console.log("testeB");               
                console.log(filtrado);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
}
```

O problema com esse código é que ele trava quando chega a hora de executar o "itens.filter", a ultima coisa que ele exibe no console é o "testeA"

O que eu gostaria de fazer é por exemplo, digamos que eu tivesse pessoas nesse array, passar como parâmetro via url a idade, mais ou menos assim '/v1/pessoas/idade/x' onde x é a idade escolhida pelo usuário, e assim só enviar para o navegador a lista com as pessoas que já atendem a esse critério.

Espero ter conseguido explicar bem minha duvida, mas caso tenha ficado confuso me falem que tentarei reformular minha pergunta.

Obrigado a todos desde já.

Comment: Qual é a propriedade no Mongo que corresponde à idade?

Comment: {"_id":"59ab81944356843198769bcb"
"nome":"João"
"idade":20
"endereço":"Rua X, Bairro Y, Rio de Janeiro"
"ocupação":"estudante"
"sexo":"masculino"
"__v":0}

Um exemplo de dado salvo no banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que vc não deixa o mongodb fazer isto para vc, busque no mongodb usando a querry dele... ex:

```
model.find({idade:req.query.idade}).then((result) => {
     res.json(result)
}, (err) => {
     res.status(500).json({error: err})
})
```

Desta forma vc poderia chamar da seguinte forma: /api/pessoas?idade=15. Recomendo que vc de uma estudada sobre os padrões de uma api RestFull